# glue multiples text boxes into one string

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am coding a web application in ruby on rails.
I have a set of text boxes in each one there is a character and i want to glue all these text boxes in order to make one word.
The text boxes are like this :

1 %>

any ideas ??

Comment: div>
  <% for i in (1..10) %>
      <%= f.text_field :password, :maxlength => 1 %>
  <% end %>
  </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for starters dont use a for loop, they ugly.

Second I wouldn't use the text_field helper rather the text_field tag

```
<% (1..10).each do |n| %>
 <%= text_field_tag "password[#{n}]" %>
<% end %>
```

That will return the password all nicely chunked up